# python plotly Treemap ids format and how to display multiple duplicated labels in a treemap?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

#### In brief

I think my question has two parts:

1. What format does `plotly` expect the `ids` argument to be in?
2. How can I create `ids` that allow me to create a treemap with a duplicated label?

#### In more detail

I'm trying to have a nested treemap with a shared label. For example, think of it as an "Other" category. 
Here I am using Python 3.8 Plotly 4.9.0

Repurposing a `plotly` example:

```py
from plotly import graph_objects as go
labels = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "Other", "Other"]
parents = ["", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "", "B1", "A1", "B1"]
ids = [f"{parents[i]}{'-' if parents[i] else ''}{labels[i]}" for i in range(0,len(labels))]
# ['A1', 'A1-A2', 'A2-A3', 'A3-A4', 'A4-A5', 'B1', 'B1-B2', 'A1-Other', 'B1-Other']

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = labels,
    parents = parents,
    ids=ids # commenting this out displays something at least
))
fig.show()
```

The above gives me a blank screen, but if I comment out the `ids` argument it ignores one of the duplicated labels:
[image: What is displayed]

I've looked at various bits of `plotly` documentation and it seems like this list of strings should work as intended.

Extract from https://plotly.com/python/reference/treemap/:

> ids 
> Type: list, numpy array, or Pandas series of numbers, strings, or
> datetimes.
>
> Assigns id labels to each datum. These ids for object constancy of
> data points during animation. Should be an array of strings, not
> numbers or any other type.

The reason I tried this specific structure of the `ids` was due to other `plotly` examples 
e.g. https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#controlling-text-fontsize-with-uniformtext

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/718417069ead87650b90472464c7565dc8c2cb1c/sunburst-coffee-flavors-complete.csv')

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
        ids = df.ids,
        labels = df.labels,
        parents = df.parents))
fig.update_layout(uniformtext=dict(minsize=10, mode='hide'))
fig.show()

# Above is exact example, below is df structure
df.head()
                       ids            labels parents
0                   Aromas            Aromas     NaN
1                   Tastes            Tastes     NaN
2         Aromas-Enzymatic         Enzymatic  Aromas
3    Aromas-Sugar Browning    Sugar Browning  Aromas
4  Aromas-Dry Distillation  Dry Distillation  Aromas
```

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Parent](https://plotly.com/python/reference/treemap/#treemap-parents): data[type=treemap]
> Type: list, numpy array, or Pandas series of numbers, strings, or datetimes.
> Sets the parent sectors for each of the sectors. Empty string items '' are understood to reference the root node in the hierarchy. If `ids` is filled, `parents` items are understood to be "ids" themselves. When `ids` is not set, plotly attempts to find matching items in `labels`, but beware they must be unique.

labels can be anything you want, ids have to be unique and parent should contain ids not labels if you are using ids.
If you are not using ids then it will figure out as stated above.

sample code:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

ids =    ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", "o_1", "o_2"]
labels = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "Other", "Other"]
parents = ["", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "", "b1", "a1", "b1"]

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = labels,
    parents = parents,
    ids=ids
))
fig.show()
```

[image: sample image]