# Create a treemap showing directory structure with plotly graph object

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to create a treemap that shows the folders in a given directory, including all subfolders and files using [plotly.graph_objects.Treemap](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Treemap.html). I understand simple examples like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64393535/python-plotly-treemap-ids-format-and-how-to-display-multiple-duplicated-labels-i) and this [one](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#controlling-text-fontsize-with-uniformtext).

**Problem:** I can't figure out how to generate the `ids` column to make my figure render properly. I'm going to have duplicate `labels`, so I need to use `ids`. Right now, the figure renders blank.

**Code:**

Here's some code to generate a sample directory structure to help you help me:

```
import os

folder = 'Documents'

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(100):
        path = os.path.join(folder, f'folder_{i}', f'sub-folder-{j}')
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        for k in range(20):
            with open(os.path.join(path, f'file_{k + 1}.txt'), 'w') as file_out:
                file_out.write(f'Hello from file {k + 1}!\n')
```

Here's the code to calculate the files sizes and create the treemap:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

directory = '[input your directory here]/Documents'

def calculate_size(folder):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        relpath = Path(root).relative_to(Path(folder).parent)

        # Calculate directory size
        dir_size = sum(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name)) for name in files)
        result.append({
            'parents': str(relpath),
            'labels': str(Path(root).name),
            'size': dir_size,
            'ids': str(relpath),
        })

        # Calculate individual file size
        for f in files:
            fp = os.path.join(root, f)
            relpath_fp = Path(fp).relative_to(Path(folder).parent)
            result.append({
                'parents': str(relpath_fp),
                'labels': str(Path(fp).name),
                'size': os.path.getsize(fp),
                'ids': str(relpath_fp),
            })

    return result

result = calculate_size(directory)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

# Set root
df.loc[df.index == 0, 'parents'] = ""

labels = df['labels'].tolist()
parents = df['parents'].tolist()
ids = df['ids'].tolist()
values = df['size'].tolist()

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = labels,
    parents = parents,
    ids = ids,
    values = values,
    # maxdepth=3
))
  
fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))

fig.show()
```

Comment: There is an 6th example in the reference that uses data frames, and I think the structure of the data gives a clue; I think the ID column can be handled by adding it later. So I think that if data can be created for each level of the directory hierarchy, a graph can be created. However, you do not need a row for only folder totals with child folders. For it will be represented by child folders.
Including files makes them illegible from the visualization point of view, so I think it is necessary to limit the data to only the top-level files that have disks, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close. However, your ids and parents will be different when you have a multi-tiered treemap. Together they create the map for Plotly.

Here I've added another function.

```
def parPath(idpath):
    """determine if path is top or not, then determine parent path"""
    if idpath == os.path.split(directory)[1]:
        parpath = idpath
    else: 
        parpath = os.path.split(idpath)[0]
    return parpath
```

This function, `parPath`, is called within your function, `calculate_size`.
There are four changes in this function (noted with comments).

```
def calculate_size(folder):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        relpath = Path(root).relative_to(Path(folder).parent)

        newpar = parPath(relpath) # determine if parent and id are different

        # Calculate directory size
        dir_size = sum(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name)) for name in files)
        result.append({
            'parents': str(newpar),                      # was str(relpath)
            'labels': str(Path(root).name),
            'size': dir_size,
            'ids': str(relpath),
        })

        # Calculate individual file size
        for f in files:
            fp = os.path.join(root, f)
            relpath_fp = Path(fp).relative_to(Path(folder).parent)

            newpar2 = parPath(relpath_fp) # determine if parent and id are different

            result.append({
                'parents': str(newpar2),                 # was str(relpath)
                'labels': str(Path(fp).name),
                'size': os.path.getsize(fp),
                'ids': str(relpath_fp),
            })

    return result
```

There is another modification in addition to your call to change the first parent; you'll also change the first `id`.

```
df.loc[df.index == 0, 'ids'] = os.path.split(df.loc[0, 'ids'])[1] # get first folder
```

You're ready to plot.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = labels,
    parents = parents,
    ids = ids,
    values = values,
))
  
fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))

fig.show()
```

Here's a drill down into one of my own folders that I used in testing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've been thinking about this for far too long. I can finally sleep at night.

Answer (score 0):

You could use plotly.express to create your treemap. You need to create a new column for each level in the treemap (used a regex to extract that information from the parents column in your dataframe).

```py
df['level1'] = df['parents'].str.replace(pat = '^(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*)', repl = r'\1')
df['level2'] = df['parents'].str.replace(pat = '^(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*)', repl = r'\2')
df['level3'] = df['parents'].str.replace(pat = '^(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*)', repl = r'\3')
df['level4'] = df['parents'].str.replace(pat = '^(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*?)\\\\(.*)', repl = r'\4')

df = df.query("labels.str.contains('.txt')")

fig = px.treemap(df,
    title = 'treemap of folder structure',
    values = 'size',
    path = ['level1', 'level2', 'level3', 'level4'],
    maxdepth = 2,
                    )
```

[image]

Comment: I'm doing testing with ``plotly-python`` but will implement it in ``plotly-react.js``, so in the end I will need to use ``plotly.graph_objects.Treemap``. I didn't have an issues creating the treemap with ``plotly.express``. Also, the number of elements provided to ``path`` will vary. I appreciate you taking the time to reply!